# Angular directive inside ng-repeat getting pre-compiled value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing what I thought would be simple directive to take any text within an `ng-repeat` and if greater than 50 characters, strip the rest of the text and add an ellipses. My repeat is simply defined as:

```
<li ng-repeat="result in topSuggestions.suggestions">
    <h4>{{result.title}</h4>
    <p suggestion-limiter>{{result.text}}</p>
</li>
```

And the directive:

```
app.directive("suggestionLimiter", [function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log($(elem).text());
            var maxTextLength = 50;
            var ellipses = "...";
            var currentText = $(elem).text();

            if (currentText.length > maxTextLength) {
                 currentText = currentText.substr(0, maxTextLength - ellipses.length) + ellipses;
                 $(elem).text(currentText);
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

The `console.log($(elem).text())` is resulting in `{{result.text}}`. I've tried using `if (scope.$last)` to wait for the `ng-repeat` to finish but still got the same result. Something simple I'm missing on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the other hand, I don't think a directive is a proper fit for this job. Using a filter instead of a directive to change the result of an expression. Something similar to this:

```
filter('ellipsis', function() {
  var ellipsis = '...';
  return function(text, limit) {
    text = typeof(text) !== 'undefined'? text: '';
    return text.length > limit?
      (text.substr(0, limit - ellipsis.length) + ellipsis):
      text;
  }
});
```

and then somehow use it like this in the context of your ng-repeat

```
 <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="item in list" ng-bind="item|ellipsis:50"></li>
 </ul>
```

Check this working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/VdxvtZdiIFRsvFNKqwTf?p=preview) I've made.

Comment: I like that approach the best. Allow for a string delimiter to be passed in for the overflow text and bang!

Comment: Ohh didn't even think of this.. testing 'er out - worked like a charm. Awesome example - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap the function body with a `$timeout(function() { ... });`. This should ensure that data binding has been finished.

```
app.directive("suggestionLimiter", ["$timeout", function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            $timeout(function() {
                console.log($(elem).text());
                var maxTextLength = 50;
                var ellipses = "...";
                var currentText = $(elem).text();

                if (currentText.length > maxTextLength) {
                    currentText = currentText.substr(0, maxTextLength - ellipses.length) + ellipses;
                    $(elem).text(currentText);
                }
            });
         }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Yup - that did it - was hoping to avoid the `$timeout` for a duration of `1` -- but alas here we are. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm also currently working on a Angular-driven SPA and haven't found any solution better than this so far. Feels dirty somehow ;)

Comment: I think its better to have the directive as a filter instead. It creates a more dynamic feel in case you would like to change the length of the text to be delimited. I have just posted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your text a data attribute of the directive and observe it for changes, negates the need for a timeout. (Code is very rough but demonstrates the basic idea.)
Edited to update the code to make it more data-attribute driven since the solution is in that vein.

http://plnkr.co/edit/n4Y89BY5KfZDpBBZJldz?p=preview

```
<body ng-controller="test">
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

<div ng-repeat="item in data">
  <span data-limit="5" 
        data-overflow-text = ".."
        data-text="{{item}}" 
        suggestion-limiter></span>
</div>
<script>

  var app=angular.module("app",[]);

  app.directive("suggestionLimiter", function () {

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

            var maxTextLength = attrs.limit*1,
                overflowText = attrs.overflowText;

            attrs.$observe("text",function(v){
              if (v.length > maxTextLength) {
                 v = v.substr(0, maxTextLength - overflowText.length) + overflowText;
                 $(elem).text(v);
            }
            });


          }

        }
  });

app.controller("test", function($scope){

  $scope.data=[ "ssssssdsadsdddddd",
                "sssdsadsdddddikk",
                "adsssssssssdsadsdddod",
                "adsssssssssdsadsddioddd",
                "adsssssssssdsadsddkk'pdd",
                "8-adsdddddd",
                "6767ddd88809909"];
});

angular.bootstrap(document,["app"]);
</script>
```